# Is there a memory-efficient way to create millions of etree.ElementTree objects?

Tags: python, xml, memory, elementtree

This (simplified from the real code - to be clear, I'm not really creating 4000 identical rows, or 100 identical cells) rapidly consumes memory:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

rows = []
shared_strings = []
for row_number in xrange(1, 4000):
    row = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}row', {'r': str(row_number), 'spans': '1:100'})
    for column_number, value in enumerate("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~abcdefg"):
        attrib = {'r': 'A%s' % row_number, 't': 's'}
        c = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}c', attrib)
        ss = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}si')
        sst = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}t')
        sst.text = value
        ss.append(sst)
        shared_strings.append(ss)
        v = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main}v')
        v.text = "4001"
        c.append(v)
        row.append(c)
    rows.append(row)
```

Basically, I'm creating a bunch of nested `Elements` - 100 'cells' that are made up of one 'value' each and 100 'shared strings' that are made up of one 'text' each, so 400 `Elements` in total, repeated 4000 times (so 1.6M `Elements` all up).

This uses well over a GB of memory (and in practice I actually need the 4000 and 100 numbers to be larger), so perhaps 600 or so bytes per Element.

I'm not that familiar with etree - is there some way I can do this more (memory) efficiently?  Would it be better to flatten the tree into a string at points and then recreate the tree from larger segments?  Or do I need to flatten it at points and leave it flattened?  (I'm generating a file when it's all done, so I don't have any need for the tree structure other than to create it).

(If it helps, and in case it's not obvious from the schemas, the code is creating a piece of an xlsx file. Obviously I have no ability to convince Microsoft that the shared string structure is pointless).

(Using Python 2.7, OS X or Debian).

Comment: Why do you need to repeat it 4000+ times?

Comment: @RobWatts because there are more than 4000 rows in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 2):

For writing out xml, sometimes, it's easier, and quicker, to write out the xml as text strings. This way, you don't have to build the entire thing in memory first.